# How can I see several maximum values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns:

```
А                B

ice cream        6
cookie           8
jam              10
cupcake          2
```

I need to find two maximum values in the B column, corresponding name in the A column and print them.

Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: What if there are two values `10` would you want to see `10` twice or `10, 10, 8`?

Answer (score 3):

```
print( df.sort_values('B', ascending=False).head(2) )
```

Prints:

```
        А   B
2     jam  10
1  cookie   8
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) the get the indexes and use `loc` to filter the dataframe:

```
df.loc[df['B'].nlargest(2).index]
```

Output:

```
        А   B
2     jam  10
1  cookie   8
```

---

Or, you can use rank and to return multiple values of the top highest 2.

Where df1 looks like this:

```
           А   B
0  ice cream   6
1     cookie   8
2        jam  10
3    cupcake   2
4      jelly  10
```

Use,

```
df1[df1['B'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False) <= 2]
```

Output:

```
        А   B
1  cookie   8
2     jam  10
4   jelly  10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.sort_values(by='B', ascending=False)['B'].drop_duplicates()[:2].tolist()
```

The `drop_duplicates()` is necessary, since otherwise you could get duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rank`

```
df[df.B.rank(ascending=False)<=2]
Out[271]: 
        А   B
1  cookie   8
2     jam  10
```